# Continuous on topology space

Tags: analysis, continuity

I believe that $f\colon [0,2\pi)\to S^1$ given $f\, x=e^{i x}$ is continuous.

However, by definition.

A map of topological spaces $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}\, U$ is
open whenever $U$ is open in $Y$.

Then I believe $\{x \mid Re (x)>\sqrt{2}/2\}$ is an open set. However, its inverse image $[0,\pi /4)\cup (2\pi - \pi /4,2\pi)$ is not an open set? What is wrong with my understanding?

Many thanks, there are plenty of duplicated questions, but I can still not get the definition on this specific example.

I also believe that the inverse of this function is discontinuous at $1$ because of the jump from $0$ to $2\pi$. However, I cannot find a counterexample against the definition.

Comment: It is open as a subset of $[0, 2 \pi)$ and that is what matters here.

Comment: The given set is open in the subspace topology on $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: So we say $[0,\pi /4)\cup ((2-1/4) \pi)$ is a open set?

Comment: Yes, recall that $A=(-1,\pi/4)\cup(2\pi-\pi/4,2\pi)$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and the set in question is nothing but $A\cap[0,2\pi)$, i.e. open in subspace topology on $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: That makes sense to me, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see whether the inverse image is open in the subspace topology on $[0,2\pi)$. Indeed, recall that $A=(−1,\pi/4)\cup(2\pi−\pi/4,2\pi)$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and the set in question is nothing but $A\cap[0,2\pi)$, i.e. open in subspace topology on $[0,2\pi)$. In fact this map is continuous.

For your second question, indeed the inverse of the function makes a jump at $1$ and is discontinuous. Take $B=[0,\pi)$, then $f(B)$ is the semi-closed semi-circle in the upper half of the Argand plane which is not open in the subspace topology on $S^1$.

Comment: Many thanks for both answering! So the problem for a semi-closed semi-circle is at point $1$, which does not have an open ball that contains $1$; thus, it's not an open set. Is this right?

Comment: @JoeYan That is correct. The basis elements of the subspace topology on $S^1$ are open arcs.