# Examples about homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

So I am demanded to offer a continuous bijection between two homeomorphic spaces that is not a homeomorphism.

As a beginner for topology, I am completely stuck. Can anyone offer me a hint?

Comment: I don't think that that's an appropriate question to ask a beginner.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086442/continuous-on-topology-space/4086455#4086455

Comment: Yeah there are some examples, but I am still not sure whether these spaces are homeomorphic.....